# Kotlin-Moshi adapter for parameterized type

Tags: android, kotlin, adapter, moshi

I have a parameterized base class

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class BaseResponse<T>(

    @Json(name = "message")
    val message: String?,

    @Json(name = "data")
    val data: T? = null
)
```

I want to get parse a JSON string and get the `message` value

```
private inline fun <reified T> getMessage(): String? {
    return try {
        val jsonStr = "{\"message\":\"Email or password not provided\"}"
        val types = Types.newParameterizedType(
            BaseResponse::class.java,
            T::class.java
        )
        val moshiAdapter = Moshi.Builder().build().adapter(types)
        val baseResponse = moshiAdapter.fromJson(jsonStr)
        baseResponse?.message
    } catch (exception: Exception) {
        null
    }
}
```

Got compile error at the adapter function

[image]

How I call this function

```
val str = getMessage<Any>()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not specifying that you're parsing a BaseResponse, just replace your adapter creation by this

```kotlin
val moshiAdapter = Moshi.Builder().build().adapter<BaseResponse<T>>(types)
```